# WGET to follow redirections from one domain to other

Tags: redirect, scripting, wget

I'm trying to set WGET to follow redirects in the case a website has changed its domain.
Example:

old_domain = "www.example.es"
NEW_domain = "www.example.COM"

The WGET command I have at the moment can't reach the NEW domain if it starts from the "old_domain":

```
wget
    --continue
    -rH
    --adjust-extension
    -Dexample www.example.es 
    --directory-prefix output/folder/
```

Is there any way to achieve it using WGET?

Comment: Does your old domain server actually server a HTTP redirect to its clients?

Comment: Some versions of wget have a  `--max-redirect option`

Specifies the maximum number of redirections to follow for a resource. The default is 20, which is usually far more than necessary. However, on those occasions where you want to allow more (or fewer), this is the option to use.
[link](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html)

Comment: To follow a redirection under the same domain it is OK. But what I do not know how to achieve is to follow one redirection outside to the original domain. 

e.g: 
wget www.example.es
www.example.es --> REDIRECTS TO --> www.example.com
wget www.example.com

Is there any option to do this with WGET?